# cloud.aws.jdbc.datasource Throwing Assertion Error: Password Must Not Be Null for Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, spring-cloud, amazon-rds, spring-cloud-aws

I'm currently working on a project in which our app needs to connect to an Amazon RDS instance. So far, I have been utilizing the following documentation for setup: 
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sdk_credentials_configuration.

According to the documentation, section 7.3, I should set my application.properties file as so:

```
cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
cloud.aws.credentials.instanceProfile=true

cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-2

cloud.aws.rds.instanceNameTest
cloud.aws.rds.instanceNameTest.password=chownTestPW
cloud.aws.rds.instanceNameTest.username=dataTest1
cloud.aws.rds.instanceNameTest.databaseName=testDB
```

However, when I run the application, I receive the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Password must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceInformation.<init>(DataSourceInformation.java:65) ~[spring-cloud-aws-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.fromRdsInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:187) ~[spring-cloud-aws-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createDataSourceInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-aws-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:130) ~[spring-cloud-aws-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.rds.AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.createInstance(AmazonRdsDataSourceFactoryBean.java:45) ~[spring-cloud-aws-jdbc-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:141) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
... 30 common frames omitted
```

I'm not sure why it's telling me that the password is null when the setup appears to be fine above.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that's an error from RDS, as your question title seems to imply.  That looks like a local assertion failure ("at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull...").

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Im glad you mentioned that. Yes, the title implies that it is an Amazon error, but it might be that I am incorrectly setting up the instance within my Spring Boot app. The Password must not be null appears to be thrown within the org.springframework.cloud.aws.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceInformation class. It's not a local assertion within the app, that assertion lies within the cloud.aws.jdbc dependency. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Hi. How did you solved this? I am getting the same error. My RDS has a password set and I have the password property (cloud.aws.rds.instanceName.password) set in my application.properties file also. Any ideas?

Comment: @cebbens Unfortunately, I was not able to get this to work. I instead had to utilize a different way that didnt involve using spring-cloud-aws which I really wanted to use. I saw that you too commented on the bug/error I wrote on the repository in Github. Please let me know if you get it to work and I'll do that same. Thanks.

Comment: @BrandonR Thanks for your reply! Too bad that there isn't a solution so far, and that there isn't too much when googling around. I will let you know ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. I had a similar config to what you had:

```
cloud.aws.rds.springdemo
cloud.aws.rds.springdemo.databaseName=springdemo
cloud.aws.rds.springdemo.username=springdemo
cloud.aws.rds.springdemo.password=Everyday123
```

I fixed the problem by removing the property `cloud.aws.rds.springdemo`, so that only

```
cloud.aws.rds.springdemo.databaseName=springdemo
cloud.aws.rds.springdemo.username=springdemo
cloud.aws.rds.springdemo.password=Everyday123
```

remained. After that, I didn't get any assertion errors and my spring boot app was able to start.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. That's so strange because https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_sdk_credentials_configuration clearly stated to setup the way I had issues with. Thanks again.